# Why does ie9.js kill respond.js in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, respond.js

I am using bootstrap 3.0, with respond.js (https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond).

I want to use nth child-selectors with IE8, so I've also installed ie9.js:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Above the header in the usual place. This actually works brilliantly for the IE8 upgrade, however it kills the respond.js functionality.

Does anyone know what's causing this conflict?